# Revert chages in EntityCollection on click of cancel

Tags: .net, entitycollection

I have a wpf window wherein grid is bound to entityCollection. herein I add/delete a record to grid and then click cancel button. How can I revert the chages made to the entitycollection.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't EF require you to call SavChanges() before anything is saved in to the database? You don't need to add a cancel button but rather a save button.

Answer (score 1):

if your objects states were changed you can't do anything without reloading collection from server using with **Overwrite** option.

In better case you may use Memento pattern.